# Java 7: SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT: fatal, description = handshake_failure mule

Tags: java, ssl, mule, tls1.2

I'm using **java 7**, **mule 3.7.0**, I've installed **Java Cryptography Extension**

I'm trying to send a request to a server, but I'm getting:

```
java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:482)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:944)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1342)


Cipher Suites: [TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension extended_master_secret
Extension server_name, server_name: [host_name: merchant.payb.lv]
***
entry.worker.04, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 136
entry.worker.04, received EOFException: error
entry.worker.04, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
entry.worker.04, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
entry.worker.04, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
entry.worker.04, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
entry.worker.04, called closeSocket()
entry.worker.04, called close()
entry.worker.04, called closeInternal(true)
entry.worker.04, called close()
entry.worker.04, called closeInternal(true)
entry.worker.04, called close()
entry.worker.04, called closeInternal(true)
```

As I understood the problem is that there's no support for **TLSv1.2**, but there should be after I installed **Java Cryptography Extension**, can anyone help, please?

I've tried:

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2")
System.setProperty("jdk.tls.client.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2")
System.setProperty("https.cipherSuites", "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA")
```

Also tried:

```
String[] ciphers = new String[2]
ciphers[0] = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256"
ciphers[1] = "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"
SSLSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(ciphers)

String[] protocols = new String[1]
protocols[0] = "TLSv1.2";
SSLSocket.setEnabledProtocols(protocols)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm using java 7, mule 3.7.0, I've installed Java Cryptography Extension

You can't possibly have installed JCE; it's been included in Java builds since 1.5 (equivalent to 5 now). You probably mean you installed the [JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html) (link for j8 because j7 is now archived). These policy files are files that contain a policy *for* JCE -- and only needed for Oracle-previously-Sun *packages* of Java.

You don't say exactly what Java version you are using, but your trace suggests it is a RedHat-family build of OpenJDK. If so, the unlimited policy files are not needed and have no effect; OpenJDK was created in 2007 and never subjected to the 'limited' crypto policy that was designed for then-Sun Java last century. (In the last few months Oracle j8, and j9 and j10, have also eliminated most of this 'feature' at last, replacing it with an editable text item that defaults to `unlimited`.)

> As I understood the problem is that there's no support for TLSv1.2, but there should be after I installed Java Cryptography Extension,

The JCE policy files have absolutely no effect on TLS protocol support. Their only effect on TLS is to enable *ciphersuites* using AES-256, which is different and separate from the protocol -- and as above only matters in (non-recent) Sun/Oracle packages.

Java 7 does *implement* TLS 1.2 out of the box, but all of the *free* (gratis) Oracle packages (up to 7u80) *disabled* it, and 1.1, on client side by default. After end-of-life for the gratis versions, the ['advanced' i.e. pay-for-support versions reportedly did enable them at 7u131](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/javase7supportreleasenotes-1601161.html#R170_131) and I presume OpenJDK builds did the same, but can't check.

According to https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=merchant.payb.lv that server doesn't actually require AES-256 anyway; it also accepts and even *prefers* AES-128 suites and would work even for Oracle j7 *without* the unlimited policy, as long as at least TLS 1.1 is enabled. It doesn't actually require 1.2, but since the effort to enable 1.1 or 1.2 is the same you might as well go for 1.2.

> I've tried:
>   System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2")
>   System.setProperty("jdk.tls.client.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2")
>   System.setProperty("https.cipherSuites", "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA")

`https.protocols` only applies to connections using `HttpsURLConnection` (not JSSE directly) and I don't know if mule does that, either in general or on your system. `jdk.tls.client.protocols` isn't supported by the gratis versions of Oracle j7; it appears to have been added to the paid versions in 7u91 or possibly 7u95, and presumably OpenJDK the same. `https.cipherSuites` also applies only to `HttpsURLConnection` and anyway isn't needed because the default ciphersuites are fine for this server; further the server does not support any 3DES suites -- nor ECDH_RSA with *any* data cipher. (Practically nobody anywhere uses ECDH_RSA; many including this server use ECDHE_RSA and yes that second E for Ephemeral makes a very big and important difference.)

> Also tried:
>   String[] ciphers = new String[2]
>   ciphers[0] = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256"
>   ciphers[1] = "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"
>   SSLSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(ciphers)
>   String[] protocols = new String[1]
>   protocols[0] = "TLSv1.2";
>   SSLSocket.setEnabledProtocols(protocols)

That's impossible. `setEnabledCipherSuites` and `setEnabledProtocols` are nonstatic methods and must be called on an object (instance) not on the class. And it matters critically *which* object you use. As above, ciphersuites don't need to be changed at all, and the second one you try to set is wrong in two ways.

I can't reproduce your trace. It logs `WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake` (meaning 1.0) for the ClientHello, but you have concealed the data that would confirm whether it truly is 1.0. When I test with 7u80 (with unlimited policy, and without mule) defaulting to 1.0, it gets EOF like you do, but it then logs `SEND TLSv1 ALERT` and `WRITE: TLSv1 Alert` -- NOT `TLSv1.2`. And when I test with 7u80 and enabling 1.2 correctly, it connects successfully, as expected.
My only theory consistent with this evidence is that you didn't enable 1.2 correctly *and* tampered with the log.

Comment: I see, thank you for such a detailed response.
But could you please help me out enabling TLSv1.2 on 7u80 correctly?

Comment: I've also tried enabling it through adding `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` but nothing changed

Comment: One first step is to learn whether (your) mule is using `HttpsURLConnection` or not; that should be visible in the part of the stacktrace you didn't show. If you added `-Dhttps.protocols` to a `java` commandline _before_ the jar or mainclass and it didn't work, mule is _probably_ not using `HttpsURLConnection`, although it _could_ be overriding it. Identifying exactly what java you are running, and what other versions if any you could substitute (e.g. upgrades available), is likely relevant. Looking at the actual ClientHello message data to check version wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Thank you, I've solved this by rewriting the code in injected groovy script so that i used httpsurlconnection and now everything works fine, thank you for your help and for such detailed responses that i could learn some stuff from c:

Answer (score 0):

Go to connector configuration of HTTP in TLS tab ,There is option called Enabled Protocol.

Just Put the value TLSv1.2